# JavaScript stuck in a compiling loop in VSC

Tags: javascript, compilation, gulp, gulp-watch

I am trying to get my JavaScript to compile onto my site, but when I save my files, it is continually starting and finishing my gulp script, and never minifying my code either, so I cannot see my changes on the front end.

This is the message in vsc: [VSC Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKjbi.png)

This is what my CMD looks like [CMD log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgqNW.png)

This is what is at the start of my gulpfile.js

```
    // Defining requirements
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var plumber = require( 'gulp-plumber' );
var sass = require( 'gulp-sass' );
var babel = require( 'gulp-babel' );
var postcss = require( 'gulp-postcss' );
var rename = require( 'gulp-rename' );
var concat = require( 'gulp-concat' );
var uglify = require( 'gulp-uglify' );
var imagemin = require( 'gulp-imagemin' );
var sourcemaps = require( 'gulp-sourcemaps' );
var browserSync = require( 'browser-sync' ).create();
var del = require( 'del' );
var cleanCSS = require( 'gulp-clean-css' );
var autoprefixer = require( 'autoprefixer' );

// Configuration file to keep your code DRY
var cfg = require( './gulpconfig.json' );
var paths = cfg.paths;
```